# Plot multiple sets of data with tripcolor - transparency in colormaps

Tags: python, matplotlib, triangulation

I seem unable to solve this problem. I have multiple sets of data with the same x,y points. I do Delaunay triangulation and plot it with tripcolor. I read on this forum, that to plot several sets of data into the same plot, I need to specify the axis and stuff, but it doesn't seem to work for me here (beginner at matplotlib, sorry). My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri
from pylab import genfromtxt

data=genfromtxt("momentAF.txt")
data2=genfromtxt("momentZZ.txt")

x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]
z1 = data[:,4]
z2 = data2[:,4]

circle=plt.Circle((0,0),1,color="black",fill=False)

triang = tri.Triangulation(x, y)

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.add_artist(circle)
ax.tripcolor(triang, z2**2, shading='gouraud', cmap='Greens')
ax.tripcolor(triang, z1**2, shading='gouraud', cmap='Reds')
#plt.colorbar()
plt.title("ST, G'=-0.0")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:
A rough example of what I'm going for:
[image: Phase diagram]

EDIT2:
I tried to display the several data sets without setting transparency for all of them using colormap option "set_under":

```
my_cmap = cm.get_cmap("Greens")
my_cmap2 = cm.get_cmap("Reds")
my_cmap.set_under('w',alpha=0)
my_cmap2.set_under('w',alpha=0)
```

and then

```
ax.tripcolor(triang, z1**2, shading='gouraud', cmap=my_cmap, vmin=0.01)
ax.tripcolor(triang, z2**2, shading='gouraud', cmap=my_cmap2, vmin=0.01)
```

but it still only shows the region where z1 is non-zero (i.e. the region where z1 is non-zero is overwritten by white from my_cmap2, which I wanted to be transparent). I also tried masked arrays,

```
masked = np.ma.masked_where(z1<.1,z3**2)
masked2 = np.ma.masked_where(z2<.1,z4**2)

ax.tripcolor(triang, masked, shading='gouraud', cmap="Greens")
ax.tripcolor(triang, masked2, shading='gouraud', cmap="Reds")
```

still to no avail though.

Comment: You haven't explained what you got vs what you expected. Also, much easier for us to work on if you type in dummy data -- explicit arrays for `data` and `data2`, please, not links to other little files.

Comment: Hi, sorry for not specifying the problem and the data (they are just too huge to publish here). The plot is in a circle and the several data sets have non-zero values in different parts of the circle. So by plotting several datasets in one plot, I want to get areas with green, red, blue, etc. parts, which are by default in different parts of the plot (by the nature of the data), so the colors will not be overlapping. The ideal result would be the one, where the colormap would go e.g. from red to transparent, so I wouldn't have to use transparency alpha, but I am not sure, if that's possible.

Comment: `set_under` changes the `alpha` of the cmap's `lut` attribute, but it seems `TriMesh` overwrites it with the `alpha` given to `tripcolor`, which defaults to `1` if not given.

Comment: BTW, you can't pass a mask array to `tripcolor`. It only accept the `mask` argument if you give it `x,y` coordinates. You have to apply the mask on the `Triangulation` object (which is what `tripcolor` does actually, it directly pass `x,y,masked` to `Triangulation` constructor), see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that it does not work, it is just that you are plotting twice the same triangulation, only changing the color (the argument coming after triang in tripcolor signature is the color of the data points).

[Cf the doc on tripcolor :](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=tripcolor#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tripcolor)

> The next argument must be C, the array of color values, either one per point in the triangulation if color values are defined at points, or one per triangle in the triangulation if color values are defined at triangles. If there are the same number of points and triangles in the triangulation it is assumed that color values are defined at points; to force the use of color values at triangles use the kwarg facecolors*=C instead of just *C.

So what your code below is doing is plotting the triangulation `triang` with color level `z1**2` of cmap `Greens`, then plotting on top of it the exact same triangulation, just changing the color levels to `z2**2` and cmap to `Reds`.

```
ax.tripcolor(triang, z2**2, shading='gouraud', cmap='Greens')
ax.tripcolor(triang, z1**2, shading='gouraud', cmap='Reds')
```

So of course, you can only see the last plotted (the red) since it's exactly covering the first plotted (the green). You might be able to see both using transparency with `alpha` :

```
ax.tripcolor(triang, z2**2, shading='gouraud', cmap='Greens', alpha=0.5)
ax.tripcolor(triang, z1**2, shading='gouraud', cmap='Reds', alpha=0.5)
```

But the end result will be a mixture of colors (with predominance of the last plotted), I am not sure that is what you want...

Just like  cphlewis said, it will be easier to understand what you want if you show what kind of data you use, and what kind of result you want.

EDIT :

I think I found a way to do what you want using mask :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri

x = np.random.uniform(-0.7,0.7,10)
y = np.random.uniform(-0.7,0.7,10)
z1 = np.random.uniform(-1,1,10)
z2 = - z1

circle=plt.Circle((0,0),1,color="black",fill=False)

triang1 = tri.Triangulation(x, y)
triang2 = tri.Triangulation(x, y)

mask1 = np.logical_or.reduce(( np.where(z1[triang1.triangles]<=0, 1,0).T ))
mask2 = np.logical_or.reduce(( np.where(z2[triang2.triangles]<=0, 1,0).T ))

triang1.set_mask(mask1)
triang2.set_mask(mask2)

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.add_artist(circle)

t1 = ax.tripcolor(triang1, z1, shading='gouraud', cmap=matplotlib.cm.Greens, alpha=0.5)
t2 = ax.tripcolor(triang2, z2, shading='gouraud', cmap=matplotlib.cm.Reds, alpha=0.5)
```

Basically, you create a mask, and set it and `triang1`, which will control which triangle are displayed.

`triang2.triangles` is the list of triangle (actually a 3*nb_of_triangles array, basically it's an array of vertices). `z2[triang2.triangles]` gives you the corresponding zlevel for each vertice. `np.where(z2[triang2.triangles]<=0,1,0).T` test if the vertice level is zero, so if it should be masked or not. The `np.logical_or.reduce` do a logical or, so that a triangle is masked if at least one of its vertices is masked (so basically, only triangles with their vertices visible are not masked).

Note that there might be some way to implement transparency by directly editing `t1._facecolors`, but I can't really see how those are calculated...

Comment: Hi, thanks @Yann. The plot is in a circle and the several data sets have non-zero values in different parts of the circle. So by plotting several datasets in one plot, I want to get areas with green, red, blue, etc. parts, which are by default in different parts of the plot (that is the nature of the data), so they will not be overlapping.

Comment: Ok, I see what you want to do. Unfortunately, this does not seems easily doable. I thought you could create custom colormaps with non constant transparency (so triangle of low level for the cmap will appear transparent), but it does not seem possible : `matplotlib.collections.TriMesh` seems to force the alpha channel to be constant on all triangles. And I don't see any simple way to go around it as I don't know the source code of this class very well.

Comment: A  possible tweak would be to 'combine' both representations, for example : `z_combined = z1**2 - z2**2` and use it with a diverging colormap : `ax.tripcolor(triang, z_combined, shading='gouraud', cmap='RdBu')`. `z_combined` takes the values of the representation which is non-zero, and with the sign, makes it red or blue.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, this is a good idea. Indeed, theoretically this should work, the only problem with this is, that sometimes for one set of data there are nonzero values on the other side of the whole diagram. The triangulation then makes a huge triangle between these portions and covers everything beneath it in white.
Still, this helps, because with some effort I should be able to separate the sets of data into these portions, which should then do the trick.
Still, I expected fewer complications...is there maybe a different tool than matplotlib that handles these things better?

Comment: Not that I know, what you want is pretty specific, but I think I have found a better solution. See my new edit.